# Helm: How to add unclassified tag in Jenkins values.yaml

Tags: helm-jenkins

I installed Jenkins (https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) Helm Chart as a requirement in my own chart.

I'm trying to add the the sonarGlobalConfiguration to the installation:

```
unclassified:
    sonarGlobalConfiguration:
      installations:
        - name: sonar
          serverUrl: 'http://sonar.local.host'
```

This code works fine with docker, but not with the Jenkins Chart, any idea under which tag i can add it?

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

This solved it:

```
JCasC:
  enabled: true
  defaultConfig: true
  configScripts:
    globalConfig: |
      unclassified:
        sonarGlobalConfiguration:
          buildWrapperEnabled: true
          installations:
            - name: "sonar"
              serverUrl: "http://delivery-pipeline-sonarqube:9000"
```